# Javascript design pattern?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, design-patterns

I wanted to comment on a question about interface design and I wanted opinions about the viability, I have a web application that will ship with a software product, this web application will be hosted on the web server the user to choose and serve to interact with the final product, but not understand much what I have to say is that this application will not be hosted in Internet and will be indexed by search engines, but will stay in "local" to each user.

Well, the issue is that I want to do something like gmail, I mean like the interface, ie a menu on the left side and as you select paint the info on the right side, but do it without iframes clear that are now deprecated.
That is, would a single html and javascript the rest would be logical, the project has its share ajax to communicate with the server hosting the info, but clear thinking would be structured as a page, the portion of the right would be a div tag I'm painting and paint removal, do not know if I going with this .... catching

My question is whether it is advisable to divide, I think gmail uses iframes but I'm not sure what I have for sure is that I do not want to do it, someone has run an application like this? faded paint and the right div as to click the menu on the left?

I hope you give me your opinion.
Thank you very much and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iframe is not depreciated at all.  In fact, the HTML5 draft adds two new attributes for the tag itself.

[iframe in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html)

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers now come with built-in developer tools (for FF it comes as an extension) that allow you to, among many other features, inspect the DOM structure of any webpage. (for example, in Chrome you can just right-click anything and choose inspect-element). This would let you know how Gmail menus are implemented (and I doubt they would use iframes for that).

Anyway, in general it is a bad idea to use iframes for structuring menus and other navigational elements. iframes are slow, inflexible and complicated  and nowadays you can get almost any layout anyway with smart use of CSS so save iframes for when you actually want to include another webpage in your site.